# Dell U2520D monitor going black every couple of seconds

Tags: 22.04, multiple-monitors

I am running Ubuntu 22.04 and I have connected two Dell U2420D monitors.

The center monitor is connected via USB Type-C and the right one connects to the center one via DP.

For whatever reason, the center monitor keeps getting completely black every couple of seconds. Both screens are on 2560x1440 at 59.96 Hz.

Not sure what's causing this problem.